# Insert Image to a Document

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ms-word

I am new to VC++, I want to know if it is possible to insert an image created by my kinect camera to a RTF doc or MSWord doc using VC++ in a Win32Console Application? Any pointers on how can I achieve my goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I assume that you already have a way to get the image from the camera and save it to a file. RTF ([*specification*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140277%28v=office.10%29.aspx)) is an utter pig, but the spec will tell you how to add an image. Parsing an existing file to figure out *where* to add the image though, or creating a new file with the image already present, is an exercise I'll leave to you.

If you have any experience with COM then adding an image to a Word document might prove easier. This MSDN page ([*link*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178792%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)) will help.